How to calculate similarity/distance in a Siamese network (pytorch)
How exactly do you calculate the similarity/distance in a Siamese network, and classify them after?
This is my current attempt
class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.resnet = torchvision.models.resnet18(num_classes=5)

    def forward_once(self, item):
        output = self.resnet(item)
        return output

    def forward(self, anchor, positive, negative):
        output1 = self.forward_once(anchor)
        output2 = self.forward_once(positive)
        output3 = self.forward_once(negative)

        return output1, output2, output3

I use resnet and TripletMarginLoss as the loss function but i'm confused on how to calculate similarity and classify the output after
also if you find anything wrong about the code please tell me.

TripletMarginLoss uses an underlying p-norm distance. If you are using the default parameter for p=2, then you should use euclidean distance to compute the similarity of embeddings.
Classification requires a labeled classification dataset and a a separate loss for classification, the same as any standard classification problem. Similarity loss does not give you classification.

What loss do i use then? also can you provide a code example
